# how to include perl script in html

Tags: php, perl

This is my php code and I have got this code in perl script.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
            setcookie("user", $_REQUEST["username"], time()-86400);
        }
        session_destroy();
    header("location:index.php");
```

Well there is just one prolblem I am facing, I need to inlcude this index.pl (in code it is index.php but I have wrote  the same code into perl script) in the code the same way as in php code.
Can I use, this to include

```
<!--#exec cgi = "/index.pl"-->
```

But what about header in php code.
I use xampp server.

Plz help.

Comment: You question is horribly explained, please elaborate and be clear. Thank you. -

Comment: This question is a bit of a muddle. How are you processing this file (what web server are you using, what configuration do you have that would process the `#exec cgi` line)? And is the PHP code just a second question? If so, please [edit] to keep to one question per page. You might want to take the [tour] to understand how things work on this site.

Comment: There is no such word as ***Plz***. You're not sending a text message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use SSI to send HTTP headers; by the time the SSI runs, it is too late.

You should approach the problem from the opposite direction and have Perl generate the whole page (using [PSGI](https://plackperl.org/)), preferably using a template language (such as [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate)), possibly using a MVC framework (such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)).

Comment: But then i have to write the whole code again. Is there any other way i can just include the .pl file in the code.

Comment: You could exec it locally (security risk), and handle the output as a string in php and echo it where it goes. But thats quite the kludge.